# Function to accept generic IEnumerable of KeyValuePair

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write an extension method that will be useful for quickly seeing the contents of a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>`. I'm having a bit of trouble writing my signature properly. The code below works with strings, but I want to be able to use it on any generic type of KeyValuePair. If  change it to accept `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<object, object>>` then try to call it on a `Dictionary<string,string>` type I get a compiler error "Instance argument: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>'" even though `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` implements interface `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`.

```
public static string ToHumanReadableString(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> dictionary)
{
  if (dictionary.IsNull())
  {
    return "{null}";
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in dictionary)
  {
    if (!kvp.Value.IsNull())
    {
      sb.AppendLineAndFormat("{0}={1}", kvp.Key.ToString(), kvp.Value.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
      sb.AppendLineAndFormat("{0}={null}", kvp.Key.ToString());
    }
  }
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why not make your method generic on TKey and TValue?

Comment: Can you post your code? I tried changing the signature to `public static string ToHumanReadableString(this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> dictionary)` but it says "The type or namespace 'TKey' could not be found"

Comment: You have to put the angle brackets with tkey and tvalue before the parens as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the function generic, like this:

```
public static string ToHumanReadableString<TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> dictionary)
    where TKey : class
    where TValue : class
{
    if (dictionary.IsNull())
    {
        return "{null}";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
    {
        if (!kvp.Value.IsNull())
        {
            sb.AppendLineAndFormat("{0}={1}", kvp.Key.ToString(), kvp.Value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendLineAndFormat("{0}={null}", kvp.Key.ToString());
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note that I've also added [constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) that the `TKey` and `TValue` types must be classes, otherwise your null checks wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: Not sure where `IsNull()` is defined but a null check should not be a problem even for value types (it will of course always be false), so the constraint to a `class` should not be necessary (and would prevent it from working for numeric types)

Comment: @DStanley Presumably this was an also extension method OP wrote. So it's not entirely clear if this is necessary. I wanted to provide the note about constraint because it seemed like OP trying use it with classes, but yes, if OP needs to use it with structs, the constraints could be dropped.

Comment: @DStanley `IsNull()` and `AppendLineAndFormat()` are extension methods I wrote or found online. They're not really important to the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can make the method generic (note changes in comments):

```
public static string ToHumanReadableString<TKey, TValue>(
    this IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> dictionary)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        return "{null}";
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var kvp in dictionary)  // note change
    {
        if (kvp.Value == null)   // note change
        {
            sb.AppendLineAndFormat("{0}={1}", kvp.Key.ToString(), kvp.Value.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            sb.AppendLineAndFormat("{0}={null}", kvp.Key.ToString());
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Note that I also formatted your brackets to use more standard indenting.

Comment: His indenting was fine, it was just tabs. SO doesn't like them.

Comment: I used tabs yes, but I also prefer block style indenting,.